# How to split a string by the third .(dot) delimiter

Tags: bash, shell, string, split

I did a few research, I can split the string by '.' but the only thing I want to replace is the third '.', and the version number is actually variable so how can I do the replace/split?

```
version: 1.8.0.110
```

but What I want is the output like this:

```
version: 1.8.0-110
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Used `sed` for example:

```
$ echo 'version: 1.8.0.110' | sed 's/\./-/3'
version: 1.8.0-110
```

Explanation:

`sed s/search/replace/x` searches for a string and replaces it with another string. `x` determines which occurence to replace - here the 3rd.  Often `g` is used for `x` to mean all occurances.

Here we wish to replace the dot `.` but this is a special character in the regular expression `sed` expects in the `search` term.  Therefore we backslashify the `.` to `\.` to specify a literal `.`.

Since we use special characters in the argument to `sed` (here, the backslash `\`) we need to put the whole argument in single quotes `''`.  Many people always use quotes here so as not to run into problems when using characters that might be special to the shell (like space  ).

Answer (score 5):

## Use bash

You do not need an external program to do this, especially since it appears you want to replace the *last* period with a dash. Bash can handle string manipulations itself.

Presuming you have

```
vers='version: 1.8.0.110'
```

the answer is simply:

```bsh
$ echo ${vers%.*}-${vers##*.}
1.8.0-110
```

The % means delete the shortest string to the right that matches. The ## means delete the longest string to the left that matches.

## What if there are more than three periods?

If you actually want to replace the third period, not the last period as I presumed above, it gets a little trickier in bash, but it is still possible. For example, if `vers='version: 1.8.0.110.hut.hut.hut.hike!'`, you can find everything after the third period and use that to truncate the string:

```
$ end=${vers#*.*.*.}
$ start=${vers%$end}
$ echo ${start%.}-$end
version: 1.8.0-110.hut.hut.hut.hike!
```

## Another way: use IFS to split string into a bash array

While this is overkill for the question, it is sometimes useful to split a string into components and load them into an array.

```
IFS=. read -a foo <<<'version: 1.8.0.110.hut.hut.hut.hike!'
```

You can iterate over the array `$foo` and choose what to print when. For example,

```
echo -n $foo
for ((i=1; i<${foo[@]}; i++)); do 
  [[ i -eq 3 ]] && echo -n - || echo -n .
  echo -n ${foo[i]};
done
echo
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the third is also the last one. If you can safely assume you always need to change the last `.`, you could do:

```
$ echo 'version: 1.8.0.110' | sed 's/\.\([^.]*\)$/-\1/'
version: 1.8.0-110
```

or, if your `sed` supports `-E` (most do) with:

```
$ echo 'version: 1.8.0.110' | sed -E 's/\.([^.]*)$/-\1/'
version: 1.8.0-110
```

That will look for a `.` and then 0 or more non-`.` characters (`[^.]`) until the end of the line (`$`). Because the `[^.]*` is in parentheses (`\( \)`), it is "captured" and can be referred to as `\1` on the right hand side of the replacement operator. So this will replace the `.` and the non`-.` characters after it with a `-` and those characters.

---

If it must be the third and not the last, [@Ned64 already gave the simplest approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/539825/22222), but as an alternative, you could do:

```
$ echo 'version: 1.8.0.110' | perl -pe 's/(([^.]+\.){2}[^.]+)\./$1-/'
version: 1.8.0-110
```